# What is equivalent to "bwlabeln (with 18 and 26-connected neighborhood)" in Python 3.x?

Tags: python, matlab, scikit-image

I have used `bwlabeln` of Matlab for three-dimensional connectives with `18-connected neighborhood`as below code:

```
[labeledImage, ~] = bwlabeln(maskImageVolume, 18); # maskImageVolume is 3D. e.g.:(200, 200, 126)
```

and equivalent of it in Python is:

```
from skimage import measure
labeledImage = measure.label(maskImageVolume, 8)
```

However, `bwlabeln` in Matlab support the `Three-dimensional connectives` (with 18 and 26-connected neighborhood) but `skimage.measure.label` just support the `4- or 8-“connectivity”`.

What is equivalent to `bwlabeln` for `18 and 26-connected neighborhood` in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation to [`skimage.measure.label`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.label) states for parameter `neighbors`:

> **neighbors : {4, 8}, int, optional**
>   Whether to use 4- or 8-“connectivity”. In 3D, 4-“connectivity” means connected pixels have to share face, whereas with 8-“connectivity”, they have to share only edge or vertex.
>   **Deprecated, use `connectivity` instead**.

And for parameter `connectivity`:

> **connectivity : int, optional**
>   Maximum number of orthogonal hops to consider a pixel/voxel as a neighbor. Accepted values are ranging from 1 to `input.ndim`. If `None`, a full connectivity of `input.ndim` is used.

What this means is that, in 3D, the connectivity can be either 1, 2 or 3, indicating 6, 18 or 26 neighbors.

Looking back through the various versions of the documentation, this syntax seems to have been introduced in scikit-image 0.11 (0.10 doesn't have it).

For your case, with 18 connected neighbors:

```
labeledImage = measure.label(maskImageVolume, connectivity=2)
```